# Hide and unhide href in row

Tags: php, html

I'm looking for solution in hiding this delete process within the row
but the problem is when I hide it and click the button to show it only the row1 show it not whole of the row in other words only row1 is executing the process of hide and unhide function not the whole row

```js
function deletebtn() {
  document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<button class="open-button" onclick="openForm()">Add File</button>
<button onclick="deletebtn()">Delete File</button>
<button>Update File</button>

<a href="process.php?remove=<?= $row['id'] ?>" class="text-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you Sure you want remove this item');"><i id="myDIV" style="float: right; display: none; " class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update with relevant code to make a [mcve]

Comment: Also one visit from Google crawler will remove all your database entries - do not have a delete in an href

Answer (score 1):

1. One visit from Google crawler will remove all your database entries - do not have a delete in an href
2. IDs need to be unique. Use delegation

Here someContainer is the main wrapper around your rows

```js
document.getElementById("someContainer").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("fa-trash")) tgt = tgt.closest("a");
  
  if (tgt.classList.contains("text-danger") && confirm('Are you Sure you want remove this item')) {
    tgt.href = "process.php?remove="+tgt.dataset.id
    return;
  }
  if (tgt.classList.contains("delete")) {
    tgt.closest("div").remove()
    return
  } 
  if (tgt.classList.contains("open-button")) {
    openForm()
    return
  } 
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="open-button">Add File</button>
<button type="button" class="delete">Delete File</button>
<button>Update File</button>

<a href="#" data-id="<?= $row['id'] ?>" class="text-danger"><i id="myDIV" style="float: right; display: none; " class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
```

If you want to POST the remove, then you need ajax

```
if (tgt.classList.contains("text-danger") && confirm('Are you Sure you want remove this item')) {

  fetch('process.php', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify({"remove":tgt.dataset.id})
  }).then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(data) {
      document.getElementById("someResultContainer").innerHTML = "Success"
  });
  return;
}
```

Comment: Why not a POST request?  You are "writing" on the server-side.

Comment: @mickmackusa I added a post, but OP has GET at the moment